# Is it possible to Draw on particular image in flutter like filling color to an Alphabet

Tags: dart, flutter, drawing

I need to allow to draw within the image boundary in flutter like filling color to an alphabet. I can adjust the canvas using height and width but how to allow to draw within particular area in flutter.[image]

Comment: use `Canvas#clipPath` for example

Comment: I tried with ClipPath and its not work for me what i expected.

Comment: because you used it the wrong way, post your code

Comment: @mk7 Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: @pskink Can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you use clipPath it should work. First you will need to create a path from your letters. There are ways to convert a png to a svg, and an sag to a path online.

Create three canvases each clipped to your letter, and then your user will only be able to draw within that path/ that letter.